# Next steps after succesfully taking image / selecting from gallery

Tags: android

I succesfully made this simple app of where you can either choose and image from gallery or take a picture: [Pick Image From Gallery Or Camera In Android Studio Programmatically](https://demonuts.com/pick-image-gallery-camera-android/). But for my purpose, where the selected image needs to serve as a profile image, I want the image to be square.
Also, some photos that are selected from gallery are rotated (Not to mention they are rectangled)

Where do I go from here in order to make user crop and rotate the image before uploading it? I want the final result to be a square image with the correct rotation.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of cropping the image, there are many [image cropping libraries for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) for you to choose from.

It is possible that one of those will also allow the user to rotate the image. If not, you will need to handle that yourself.

If you only need to allow the user to rotate the image a few ways (e.g., portrait and landscape), you could use a `Switch` or `Spinner` to allow the user to choose a rotation, then rotate the `ImageView` to show them what it looks like. Once they choose a rotation to use, you can use a `Matrix` to rotate the `Bitmap`. Ideally, you would rotate the image after cropping, as photos are large and you may run out of memory trying to rotate a photo.

Comment: I have no idea about what you say, as a beginner, it sounds like jiberish, I wish I knew where I should go from here in order to grasp what you wrote. I never knew that making a simple app to choose image will be that difficult. Also, after you showed me these libraries, I feel even more lost as to how to integrate these libraries with existing code I provided (How to make them work together?). Asking you as a professional, do you see it possible to integrate any library with the existing code I provided? Or that would be too much of a work

Comment: @TTnote: "I never knew that making a simple app to choose image will be that difficult" -- you are not writing an app to choose an image. You are writing an app to choose, crop, and rotate an image. "I wish I knew where I should go from here in order to grasp what you wrote" -- perhaps you should start with a simpler project. Or, perhaps put this project aside and read a book, take a course, or otherwise learn Android app development using existing educational materials. "Or that would be too much of a work" -- I do not know what is "too much of a work" for you.